# “Do not spell out” meaning

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the expression “do not spell out”?

It is from this context:

> you forgot your articles! Also we would not use these three in a formal letter. Use the symbol $ and do not spell out. Of the above, #2 and #6 (более вежливое) are the best. I would not use the first two versions that include both "I" and "my." Unless this is correct in BrE, I would not use #5, as it sounds too absolute.

Comment: It means *use the symbol "$" rather than writing out the word "dollar"* To 'spell out' something is to put down all the letters. The phrase is also used to mean describe something step by step rather than just naming it.

Comment: It should probably say "do not spell **it** out".

Comment: great, don’t know why i did not understand it from first time.

Comment: This is General Reference. Googling **define spell out** brings up several dictionary entries like [this one](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spell%20out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote “I paid 40 dollars”, you *spelled out* the dollar symbol (‘$’) which would normally be placed before the amount, like so: “I paid $40.”

> **spell something out**
>
> 1. *Lit.* to spell something (with letters). *I can't understand your name. Can you spell it out? Please spell out all the strange words so I can write them down correctly.*
> 2. *Fig.* to give all the details of something. *I want you to understand this completely, so I'm going to spell it out very carefully. The instruction book for my computer spells out everything very carefully.*
>    <sub>Source: McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs, via [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spell+out)</sub>